# My sailboat engine has transmission problems

Tags: transmission, troubleshooting

Tested the transmission but did not go forward or backward, so I have to repair it. I need to get the engine out of the tiny engine bay, she's 250lbs. How do I lift her? She is under the cockpit floor. It's an Albin 022.

Comment: Make an A frame? use a shore mounted crane?" either have been used...

Comment: Killjoy's . Cant we have a little fun/humor here ?

Comment: Hi polar bear hunter! Tell me your best joke :-) and we have humor. My memory is shot for whatever reason, but kinda gets reactivated when hearing good jokes. ps. an A frame is what I'm thinking about, together with a pully system. Hoping to not have to lift entire engine out, but just the transmission, so I can check it all!